# Media keys not working for iTunes (pause/play, skip buttons)

Tags: itunes, keyboard, high-sierra

I am being driven crazy by the fact that my media keys aren't working for iTunes. Such a pain! How can I fix this? I've tried the whole Chrome Extensions thing, that being I deleted all my extensions. Still, nothing has fixed this. Thanks to all who reply!

Comment: Are you using macOS High Sierra?

Comment: @Jake3231 That is correct.

Answer (score 4):

This is an intentional change in macOS High Sierra. Rather than the media keys always controlling iTunes, they will now control whatever media is playing at a given moment.

[9To5Mac](https://9to5mac.com/2017/11/15/how-to-fix-media-controls-high-sierra/) has detailed a way to change this behavior with a third-party application, [macOS High Sierra Media Key Enabler for iTunes and Spotify](http://milgra.com/high-sierra-media-key-enabler.html):

> Apple just released High Sierra and it brought good things and annoying things : they changed the behaviour of the media controller keys, they no longer control itunes, they control the video playback in safari. This pissed off a lot of people including me, so I just created a menu bar app to proxy media key events to iTunes/Spotify while Apple fixes this. It doesn't support touchbar yet, only physical buttons.